# No se marca ActionResult

Tags: c#, mvc

Estoy creando un nuevo controlador para de ahi mismo crear la vista, sin embargo ActionResult, no se marca en verde.
Como puedo solucionarlo?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Deberia de verse asi

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Que significa “no se marca en verde”?

Comment: actualice la pregunta

Comment: Probablemente hiciste la clase a mano y te faltaron using o algun otra cosa....

Comment: no se hicieron a mano, hice el controller desde Add>Controller...

Comment: Tu clase está heredando de Controller?

Comment: Entonces hay mas errores porque tampoco te reconoce View...